# Accessing child class members using pointer to a base abstact class

Tags: c++, oop, class, pointers, inheritance

```
class a //my base abstract class
{
public:
virtual void foo() = 0;
};

class b : public a //my child class with new member object
{
public:
void foo()
{}
int obj;
};

int main()
{
b bee;
a * ptr = &bee;
ptr->obj; //ERROR: class a has no member named "obj"
}
```

My question is, how can I access the "obj" member when I have a pointer to base class ("a") pointing to child class ("b") object? I know that casting should do the trick but I'm looking for better solutions.

Comment: Some context would help.  Why do you want do that?  If casting isn't an option you'll have to have a virtual function override in your derived class that returns a reference or pointer to that member.  However, that generally breaks encapsulation.  This brings us back to why you want access the derived class member through a pointer to the base class?

Comment: @Void probably you are right, I should change the design.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the `dynamic_cast<>` operator to convert a pointer to `a` to a pointer to `b`. The conversion will succeed only if the run-time type of the object pointed to by `ptr` is `b`, and will return a null pointer otherwise, so you must check the outcome after converting:

```
b* p = dynamic_cast<b*>(ptr);
if (p != nullptr)
{
    // It is safe to dereference p
    p->foo();
}
```

If you can guarantee that the type of the object pointed to by `ptr` is `b`, however, in this case (since no virtual inheritance is involved) you can even use a `static_cast<>`, which incurs in less overhead because it is performed at compile-time.

```
b* p = static_cast<b*>(ptr);
// You are assuming ptr points to an instance of b. If your assumption is
// correct, dereferencing p is safe
p->foo();
```

Answer (score 3):

You'll have to cast down the inheritance hierarchy. Your case is tailor-made for using `dynamic_cast` to the appropriate type as that allows you to check in a type-safe manner if the object you're trying to cast actually is of the expected type.

Comment: I didn't think about dynamic_cast, that should solve the problem as it's type-safe.

Answer (score 1):

In GCC and Clang (and in Visual Studio I think) you can also use the following syntactic sugar

```
if (Derived* x = dynamic_cast<Derived*>(x)) {
     // do something with \c x now that we know its defined     
}
```

and in C++11, using `auto` type inference, even nicer

```
if (auto x = dynamic_cast<Derived*>(x)) {
     // do something with \c x now that we know its defined     
}
```

and finally if we want to restrict to read-only access

```
if (const auto x = dynamic_cast<Derived*>(x)) {
     // read something from \c x now that we know its defined     
}
```

Note that this nicely limits the scope of `x` to inside the if clause(s) which is often more convenient if we do multiple successive dynamic_cast after one another using `if`'s and `else if`'s.